# Random Number Guesser not running as intended

Tags: python, windows, random

```py
import random

input = input("Guess the number from 1 to 20 Computer is thinking: ")
if input.isdigit():
    int(input)
else:
    print("Error")
    exit()
computer = int(random.randrange(1, 5))
print("Computer thinks of number", str(computer) + ".", end = " ")

if input == computer:
    print("You Win!")
elif input != computer:
    print("You Lost.")
```

Whenever I guessed the right number, It says that I lost. This is a simple project I made as a beginner so please explain in the simplest way possible

Comment: Don't post code or error messages in images or in links to external sites. Provide them in the question as formatted text.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I tried but It won't let me post the question.

Comment: @BillyCao Downvotes mean that the question is unclear or not useful to other people; it's not something that's directed towards the asker. They are meant to be objective and to guide people with similar problems to the question. Stating that you're a beginner doesn't change anything. In fact, it makes it worse as it's just unnecessary noise and should be removed. Questions should not be judged based on the user's level of expertise; questions from all levels of knowledge are welcomed.

Comment: Currently, the question is getting downvotes due to the code being in an image. [This page](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) explains just a few of the many problems with it.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Well how do you expect beginners to both programming and stack overflow to know any of this? Moreover, his code being in a picture does not prevent anyone to find the problem and answer his question, - I just did it, and it took me 1 second. If you treat everyone 'equally', beginners like him will just be discouraged by the downvotes on their first question and will never dare to ask anything again. Is this what the 'code of conduct' is supposed to achieve? Furthermore, the OP said he tried but failed, which of course I don't know why, but at least shows he knows the practices

Comment: @BillyCao Most introductory content is in the beginner tour with references to [mre] or [ask], both which mentions images. Although, it can be hard to keep track of them, which is why I wrote a comment explaining it. And it does absolutely hinder you from finding the problem, as the code in images are not searchable through a Google search query. You "found" it because it was presented as a newly asked question, but you're missing the point. The idea of SO is for other people to find older asked and answered questions in order to get help with *their* similar problem.

Comment: That's why questions are kept around after they've got an answer. It has to do with the collective good. For beginners, I usually give feedback and edit their question to be of high enough quality, but if it's not relatively easily fixable it will be downvoted and closed so it can be put in the review queue for deletion as it isn't up to standard or is not usable for *other* users. It's possible it might feel discouraging, but is a necessity to try to reduce quantity and maintain quality on the site.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue in your code is the variable not being stored.

[image]

In your provided picture here, you call `int(input)` to convert the input number into an integer, showing that you understand that `input()` returns a string (not many beginners know this!), however, you did not store the result returned by `int()` to a variable. In your case, it seems like you want to store it back to the `input` variable.

Because you did not store it, calling `int(input)` will not modify the value in the existing `input` variable, making it still string, and thus failing the comparison with the computer generated number which is an integer.

To fix this, simply replace the `int(input)` with `input = int(input)`

On a side note, it is not advisable to use variable names that are same as built-in functions, like `input`, or `str`, as doing so will override the built-in function, causing the subsequent calls to the `input()` function to return error, since now `input` is a variable, not a function anymore.